# VBA Excel Find Number in another Excel Doc And Copy Specfic Columns

Tags: excel, vba

Hi so I am not too experienced in Excel VBA. I am trying to find the values in one excel workbook in another excel workbook, then copy the corresponding B, F and K column and insert it into the B5,C5 and D5 columns.

This is what I have done so far.

```
 Sub findsomething()
Dim rng As Range
Dim account As String
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim dehyp As Long

dehyp = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
account = Sheet.Cells(dehyp)


Set rng = sheet1.List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016- 
    2021).xlsx.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=account,
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    rownumber = rng.Row
    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheet1.List-of-substances-in-the-third- 
    phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx.Cells(rownumber, 
    3).Value




End Sub
```

I have tried till the open work book part of the code and it works, but have not tested anything past it because I don't know how to do the column find.

Any help is appreciated
..............................................................................Edit: I have reformated it to include the find statement and thought maybe I do not have to open the second workbook. I am not sure what is wrong and am getting compilation errors.

Comment: Just realized that it wouldn't paste it in B5, beacuse I need to specify the second work book and the specific cell before. Apologies in advance.

Comment: You could possibly use [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: @BigBen so could i do range.find(dehpyh) then that would return an int for the column its in?

Comment: No you could use `.Column` on the found result for that.

Comment: @BigBen so I tried                                                                                                    
i = (range.Find(dehyph),"List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx").Column                                                                                            
and I got a compilation error

Comment: if I try just i = (Range.Find(dehyphin, "List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx")), then I get that range is not an optional argument.

Comment: To see how `Range.Find` works, record a macro using Find (Ctrl+F), or check out examples here on SO.